# Выборка заданного дня недели из CSV файла

Tags: python, дата, выборка

Один из столбцов в файле .csv несет в себе дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГ.

Как выбрать, например, все понедельники и поместить полные строки в новый файл?

---

Пример [CSV файла](https://yadi.sk/d/v2rMlDUssXEpAQ). Начинается с года, я поменял на:

```
loc[pd.to_datetime(df["<DATE>"], yearfirst=True, errors="coerce").dt.weekday == 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формат в вопросе был указан неправильно. Приведенный в комментарии CSV файл выглядит так (т.е. формат дат: `YYYYMMDD`):

```
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DATE>,<TIME>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>
SPFB.BR,D,20100111,000000,81.3800000,2871
SPFB.BR,D,20100112,000000,79.7000000,9362
SPFB.BR,D,20100113,000000,78.8900000,15234
SPFB.BR,D,20100114,000000,78.4000000,51012
SPFB.BR,D,20100115,000000,77.1200000,25672
```

Соответственно и решение будет несколько отличаться:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\05.csv", dtype={"<DATE>": str})
(df
 .loc[pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors="coerce").dt.weekday == 0]
 .to_csv("result.csv", index=False))
```

Answer (score 3):

Предположим, столбец с датами называется `Date` и имеет формат `DD.MM.YY`:

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
(df
 .loc[pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=True, errors="coerce").dt.weekday == 0]
 .to_csv("result.csv", index=False))
```

Comment: Код работает, только файл возвращает пустой. Только с заголовками. Как будто не находит ничего.

Comment: @IgorSorokin, а в вашем CSV файле точно есть даты с понедельниками? Можете выложить ваш CSV файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник, не требующий регистрации?

Comment: @IgorSorokin, вы в вопросе сказали, что формат даты `ДД.ММ.ГГ`, а на самом деле у вас `YYYYMMDD`...